# Chrome not supporting my javascript

Tags: javascript

I just want, when a user comes to my site and closes the window, then I want to know the reason for leaving from my site.

So I'm sending the user to a survey page, using the following script.

It works in every browser but not in Chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit() {
    if (location.href.indexOf("index.php") != -1)
    {
        location.href = "http://www.test.com/survey.php";
        return "Press 'cancel to go 'survey'";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Personally I am not going to answer this question because I don't believe this is good practice. You should not be re-directing users as they leave your page, I would consider that malicious.

Comment: I would certainly not answer a survey I was just forced into! And of course I will keep on using Chrome ;-)

Comment: I would bet Chrome does not do what you are looking for just because it is pretty annoying, to be fair. It is like avoiding popups. However, I am not sure.

Comment: By forcing an exit interview on users, I can guess at a few things about the site: low quality, poor content, non-existent traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `window.location = ("http://www.test.com/survey.php");` or `window.open ("http://www.test.com/survey.php");` instead? That may be easier to do.

You can also do `window.open ("http://www.test.com/survey.php", '_newtab');` This will make users less upset off when they are forced to redirect after leaving, because it will be in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes there is a good reason for such a code user310850 is quoting

1. not all websites are in Web, some of them are internal corporate websites
2. Some if not most of big companies still use IE 6 as standard browser

I would use unload event handler. I assume jquery is good

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  //your code here
});
```